# submenu being shown when user isn't logged in

Tags: html, css

The following is how the sub-menu is intended for use https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0zES.png

However, upon logging out the sub-menu is also showing - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwi1h.png - which is the issue (I would like the menu to only show up when the user is logged in).

```css
ul.sub-menu {
    posiiton:absolute;
}

.navClass > ul > li{
    font-family: arial;
    padding-left: 10%;
    margin-top: -77px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.navClass > ul{
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: sans-serif
}

ul.sub-menu{
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #cacdce;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:-25px;
    width:125px;
    padding-left:0px;
    opacity:0;
}

ul.sub-menu li{
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
   
}
ul.sub-menu li:hover{
}
.navClass li:hover{
}
.navClass li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<?php 
 include_once 'header.php';
?>

 <div class="main-wrapper">
<section class="main-container">
    <div class="awesome">
    <nav class='navClass'>
    <ul>
        <li>
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
                echo $_SESSION['u_uid'];
            }
        ?>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Profile</li>
                <li>Dashboard</li>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>

<?php 
 include_once 'footer.php';
?>

<?php

?>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated everything is provided above.

Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not too sure what that did it still shows the https://i.imgur.com/XrtoxPy.png the submenu when the user isn't logged in.

Comment: sorry for earlier. wasn't a complete response. Try adjustment with `top` instead of `margin-top` for `ul.sub-menu`. May be able to help with a fiddle if you can share code of `header.php` and its css.

Comment: The issue isn't it fitting on the page. As it fits on the page fine when the user is logged in. However, upon logging out I need the menu to not show up at all.

Comment: Which is the purpose of why I posted this :)

Comment: Now that you have edited your question to clearly state what you intend to achieve, hope my answer helps.

Comment: No worries sorry that I wasn't clear in the first place. Thank you for your comments however, they will come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `<ul class="sub-menu">` or `<nav class='navClass'>` or the top parent tag for sub-menu inside of the `if` statement, like:

```
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
            echo $_SESSION['u_uid']; ?>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Profile</li>
                <li>Dashboard</li>
    <?php } ?>
```

Also, on an unrelated but important note, do check your html structure and all the tags as many of the tags are not closed and hierarchy also seems out a little.

Comment: Great that it helped. Please don't forget to upvote the answer as well, it will help future users with similar problem.